# How to create "logging feature" in listbox in C#. Source information from other classes

Tags: c#, listbox

i have a problem with "passing" information from other classes to main Form of a program. It's a client-server application. I would like to make a "logging interface" on server main form in listbox (or something similar, doesn't really matter...) that will show for example when one client connected to server. So in my app it comes to two classes: Datebase.cs and Form.cs. When a call comes from database.cs i should modify listbox1.Text with a custom text. I tried Form1.listBox1.Items.Add(logon); but it failed :/

**Database.cs**

```
// Other classes and methods...

public class Database
{
    public string logon;
    public string logoff; 

    // some methods

    internal bool Logon(string username,string password)
    {
        // blah blah...
                logon = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Username " + username + " just logged on";
                Form.listBox1.Items.Add(logon);
    }
    internal bool Logoff(string username)
    {
            // blah blah...
            logoff = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Username " + username + " just logged off";
            Form.listBox1.Items.Add(logoff);

    }
}
```

And the other class is just a main Form with listBox1. It's set as public, it's in the same namespace, just different class.

**Form.cs (designer part)**

```
partial class Form
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this.listBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Blah blah...",
        "BLAH BLAH!"});
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 78);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
        this.listBox1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(429, 329);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(532, 465);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass `Form` instance to `Database`, or better not to update Listbox from `Database` class. Leave responsibility of updating UI (Listbox in this case) to `Form`. Let `Form` read return value of `Logon/Logoff` function, and update `Listbox` accordingly.

```
private Database _database = new Database();

private void LogonButton_Click(object sender, EventeArgs e)
{
    var logonResult = _database.Logon("username", "password");
    if(logonResult) 
    {
        logon = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Username " + username + " just logged on";
        listBox1.Items.Add(logon);
    }
}
```

The first approach by passing `Form` instance to `Database` is demonstrated below for comparison (not recommended) :

```
public class Database
{
    ....
    public Form FormInstance;

    public Database(Form formInstance)
    {
        ....
        FormInstance = formInstance;
        ....
    }
    ....
    internal bool Logon(string username,string password)
    {
        // blah blah...
        logon = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Username " + username + " just logged on";
        FormInstance.listBox1.Items.Add(logon);
    }
    .....
}

//in Form, when creating Database instance pass current Form instance as parameter
private Database _database;
public Form()
{
    ....
    _database = new Database(this);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I believe it would be very helpful for someone more advanced than me... I'm a total beginner in C#. To be really honest i don't really understand how it work with all this "instances" kind of stuff in this particular case. So i didn't tried your second solution but i was thinking a lot about your first approach.

Comment: "Leave responsibility of updating UI (Listbox in this case) to Form. Let Form read return value of Logon/Logoff function, and update Listbox accordingly." That would be great but how to achieve this? In your code after clicking Logon you passing username and password to an "instance" of database, and then on this Form from where you clicked, you updating it's Listbox. I believe you thought that it is other kind of client-server, and Form with Listbox is from client that connects to server, no it's not :P

Comment: Client is a whole separate app that is using Database.cs form Server app. So Button_Click method wont' work  but it's still a nice approach for me to learn. I need something that would update my UI on Server's Form, when a Client connects to server's Database.cs. The whole problem with this is that it was designed to be a Console app and all the "calls" was just Console.Writeline("blah blah"); I need to create this UI from scratch now but still i didn't found any answer that would got that "eureka" moment... To clarify all thing:

Comment: Client app connects to server via http, then it's using Logon method of server's Database.cs and... it should be "seen" on Server's UI which is in this case a listbox. Sorry for 4 comments, but it was too long :P

Comment: I didn't think your Form to Database relation as client-server, I thought it as two classes in single application. My solution is to answer "*which logic should be in which class*" as well. The first code block (1st solution) is all resides in Form, that assumed you have a button in Form and when it clicked `LogonButton_Click` event handler called. I still don't get why it won't work?

Comment: About the 2nd solution. The fundamental mistake in your code is you can't call non static method this way : `Form.listBox1.Items.Add(logon);`. This one will successfully compiled : `var form = new Form(); form.listBox1.Items.Add(logon);` but you won't see your Form updated, because that code updated another instance of Form class separate from the Form instance currently displayed. So the solution is to pass current Form instance to be updated instead of creating/instantiating a new one. That what the 2nd solution demonstrated.

Comment: Ok, so again about "first solution". If i understand it correctly, you mean that i have a button on Server's Form? But it wouldn't make any sense to me... I don't want to have any interaction on server-side form and to be honest i can't even imagine how it would work (clicking to check if someone logged in?). Let's stay i this scenario: I have only listbox on my Server's Form and it should be updated automatically without any "button" interaction when a Client app connects (when Logon method in Database is called up).

Comment: In your second comment you cleared a lot o things about instances to me (at least i know why it doesn't update my listbox ;P) but this line got me confused :(    private Database _database = new Database(); if you making new instance of database how this will work? Calls will come to original Database, not instance.  Another thing is that "Let Form read return value of Logon/Logoff function"... maybe I'm stupid but Logon/Logoff methods return true/false not username and password, they are boolean.

Comment: Sorry if it really is a stupid question but please explain it to me a "little" more specific :P More optimistic thing is that I nearly got that second solution. In database i created an Instance as you recommended but still i have problem with understanding 2 blocks of code    public Database(Form formInstance)
    {
        ....
        FormInstance = formInstance;
        ....
    } Why i need to pass instance as a parameter to Database constructor? It looks to me like making instance of and instance but just dont know how it work.

Comment: I did that also. Made that    FormInstance.listBox1.Items.Add(logon); call in my method and.. debugger thinks it is right but what's happening is exactly what you said "you won't see your Form updated, because that code updated another instance of Form". There comes last line that i dont understand and where to write it:     //in Form, when creating Database instance pass current Form instance as parameter
private Database _database = new Database(this); When i pasted it to Form that error occured: "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context".

Comment: Thanks in advance for all you effort :) I really apprieciate it ;)

Comment: PS: So basically the second solution work until I want to " pass current Form instance to be updated instead of creating/instantiating a new one." I doesn't work because of the last line.

Comment: responding to your PS above. That was my mistake, `this` keyword can't be called there. I moved it to constructor as shown in my updated answer. You could try it again.

Comment: Now this is what my debugger says when i'm connection my client to server (pointing at FormInstance.listBox1.Items.Add(logon);) : NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code (app crashes).

Comment: which property is null? `FormInstance` or `lsitBox1`?

Comment: FormInstance, also checked "logon" string and it have date, username etc.

Comment: Any chance you call `Logon` method on other instance of Database (apart from `_database` which `FormInstance` property already set here `_database = new Database(this);`)?

Comment: Yes, I also have "Database database = new Database();" this instance of database in my Server.cs. Could this be a reason? So how can i figure it out?

Comment: After going this far and looked at the question again, I think I got the question wrong. I assumed it is single application not a client-server. If you want to create a client-server, then the first question to ask is how to pass information from client to server. You can't call method in server from client just like that

Comment: and `Database database = new Database();` will create database instance with null `FormInstance`. You need to set the property after create the instance : `database.FormInstance = FormInstanceToBeUpdated`

Comment: Yeah, i think that whole concept of doing this UI is just wrong. The only thing i wanted to achieve was to make all the "log data" visible in Form component (like listbox). App works perfectly fine in it's console variant. Just Console.Writeline(logon); inside of Database.Logon method. To be really honest i didn't even thought that just trying to write some text could cause so many problems... Thank you very much for your effort once again ;)

Comment: and reffering to your last response: I tried some stupid things inside of Server.cs class... but couldn't make that "database.FormInstance" to work.